# Is it possible to edit data pulled using a query formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have simple query formula that pulls rows of data from one master sheet(A) to another tab(B), but like all query data I can't edit the data on the tabs(b). Is there a way to make the data editable and somehow linked to the master sheet(A)?

Ex.
On the master list I have the following

```
Jane Doe 555-555-444 jane.doe@mail.com Student
John Doe 555-666-000 john.doe@mail.com Faculty
```

I have a tab(B) named student and one tab(C) named Faculty. My query simply pulls each row to either the student or faculty tab. But if I wanted to change the data on the student tab, I can't.

Answer (score 2):

No, for the same reason that one can't shave one's reflection in a mirror.

Spreadsheets data links are one-way, with a source and a target. The source range can be edited, the target range cannot be, because its job is to reflect the data as it is present in the source.

As pnuts commented, copying and pasting back values only (e.g., Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-Shift-V) is a way to break the link of the target range with the source. Then the target will be editable, since it is no longer a reflection of the source. Consequently, it will no longer be updated if the source changes.

Comment: Great answer! reinforces the concept! Can we add a formula in the script so that we dont have to modify later?

Answer (score -2):

Certain legacy spreadsheet software can do what you need.

If you have access to 32-bit Windows, then as far as I know, your best bet lies with Lotus 1-2-3.  I recommend version 5.